# How to apply Graphics scale and translate to the TextRenderer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, paint

I'm using scaling and transforming my graphics object when painting a custom control, in order to apply zooming and scrolling. I use the following:

```
            Matrix mx = new Matrix();
            mx.Scale(mZoomFactor, mZoomFactor);
            mx.Translate(-clip.X + mGraphicsOffsetx, -clip.Y + mGraphicsOffsety);

            e.Graphics.Clip = new Region(this.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.Transform = mx;
```

Then when I paint my strings using:

```
Graphics g = ...
g.DrawString(...)
```

The scalling and transforming is correctly applied to the strings, they are zoomed out and in and so on.

However if I use the following to paint my strings:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(...)
```

The text is not correctly scaled and transformed.

Do you know how to apply this concepts to the `TextRenderer`?

Comment: It's probably not going to happen. The difference is that `Graphics.DrawString` uses GDI+ to draw the text, whereas `TextRenderer.DrawText` uses GDI (note, no plus). That's why the latter produces output that looks like the native controls, because they draw with GDI. But GDI doesn't have quite the rich support for visual fluff like transformations, and little of it is encapsulated in the `Graphics` class, which is a .NET wrapper for GDI+.

Comment: @CodyGray: This is almost an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because I'm not certain that such transformations are impossible with `TextRenderer.DrawText`. They're just not going to happen the way that you're trying to achieve them. You'll need to use another mechanism. I believe there are some overloads of the `DrawText` function that accept formatting flags that might be useful.

Comment: There is a `TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsTranslateTransform` flag available in the TextRenderer class.  Maybe that works.

Comment: @LarsTech: Did not work at all, it preserve the graphics translate but it doesn't apply the scale. Thanks.

Comment: @LarsTech - Worked well for the TextRenderer.DrawText rendered text on my non zoomable Panel That implements a ScrollBar transformation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments above are accurate--`TextRenderer.DrawText`, being GDI, has limited support for coordinate transformation given its resolution dependence.  As you've noticed, coordinate translation is supported but scaling is not (and neither is coordinate rotation).

The solution we've used (and the only resource I've been able to find on the internet) is to manually scale the `Font` and `Rectangle` objects to reflect the scaling applied by `Matrix.Scale(float, float)` in conjunction with `Graphics.Transform`:

```
    private Font GetScaledFont(Graphics g, Font f, float scale)
    {
        return new Font(f.FontFamily,
                        f.SizeInPoints * scale,
                        f.Style,
                        GraphicsUnit.Point,
                        f.GdiCharSet,
                        f.GdiVerticalFont);
    }

    private Rectangle GetScaledRect(Graphics g, Rectangle r, float scale)
    {
        return new Rectangle((int)Math.Ceiling(r.X * scale),
                            (int)Math.Ceiling(r.Y * scale),
                            (int)Math.Ceiling(r.Width * scale),
                            (int)Math.Ceiling(r.Height * scale));
    }
```

Here is the entire test form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PictureBox box = new PictureBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        box.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        box.BackColor = Color.White;

        box.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(DrawTest);
        this.Controls.Add(box);
    }

    public void DrawTest(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        string text = "Test Text";
        float scale = 1.5F;
        float translate = 200F;

        var flags = TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsTranslateTransform;

        var mx = new Matrix();
        mx.Scale(scale, scale);
        mx.Translate(translate, translate);

        g.Clip = new Region(Bounds);
        g.Transform = mx;

        Size rendererPSize = Bounds.Size;
        Font f = GetScaledFont(g, new Font("Arial", 12), scale);
        Size rendererRSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, text, f, rendererPSize, flags);

        Rectangle rendererRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, rendererRSize.Width, rendererRSize.Height);
        Rectangle r = GetScaledRect(g, rendererRect, scale);

        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, text, f, realRect, Color.Black, flags);
    }

    private Font GetScaledFont(Graphics g, Font f, float scale)
    {
        return new Font(f.FontFamily,
                        f.SizeInPoints * scale,
                        f.Style,
                        GraphicsUnit.Point,
                        f.GdiCharSet,
                        f.GdiVerticalFont);
    }

    private Rectangle GetScaledRect(Graphics g, Rectangle r, float scale)
    {
        return new Rectangle((int)Math.Ceiling(r.X * scale),
                            (int)Math.Ceiling(r.Y * scale),
                            (int)Math.Ceiling(r.Width * scale),
                            (int)Math.Ceiling(r.Height * scale));
    }
}
```